# switch case using variables, repetitive code

Tags: android, button, switch-statement

I have 50 `Buttons`. I use the `switch` statement as shown below. Each `case` has the same `On-Click` code. But I make many changes to the code for each `Button`, and it's really tedious work and very repetitive to change the code the same way 50 times. My code currently looks like this:

```
 public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {

     switch (v.getId()) {
        case button1:
            if(button_list.get(1).getTag().equals("0"))
                enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(1).getText().toString());
            is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(1).getTag();      
            if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                button_list.get(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                button_list.get(1).setTag("1"); 
            }else{
                    button_list.get(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                    button_list.get(1).setTag("0"); 
            }
            break;
        case button2:
            if(button_list.get(2).getTag().equals("0"))
                enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(2).getText().toString());
            is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(2).getTag();      
            if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                button_list.get(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                button_list.get(2).setTag("1"); 
            }else{
                    button_list.get(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                    button_list.get(2).setTag("0"); 
            }
            break;
        case button3:
            if(button_list.get(3).getTag().equals("0"))
                enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(3).getText().toString());
            is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(3).getTag();      
            if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                button_list.get(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                button_list.get(3).setTag("1"); 
            }else{
                    button_list.get(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                    button_list.get(3).setTag("0"); 
            }
            break;
        case button4:
            if(button_list.get(4).getTag().equals("0"))
                enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(4).getText().toString());
            is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(4).getTag();      
            if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                button_list.get(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                button_list.get(4).setTag("1"); 
            }else{
                    button_list.get(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                    button_list.get(4).setTag("0"); 
            }
            break;
        case button5:
            if(button_list.get(5).getTag().equals("0"))
                enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(5).getText().toString());
            is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(5).getTag();      
            if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                button_list.get(5).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                button_list.get(5).setTag("1"); 
            }else{
                    button_list.get(5).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                    button_list.get(5).setTag("0"); 
            }
            break;
        case button6:
            if(button_list.get(6).getTag().equals("0"))
                enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(6).getText().toString());
            is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(6).getTag();      
            if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                button_list.get(6).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                button_list.get(6).setTag("1"); 
            }else{
                    button_list.get(6).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                    button_list.get(6).setTag("0"); 
            }
            break;
        case button7:
            if(button_list.get(7).getTag().equals("0"))
                enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(7).getText().toString());
            is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(7).getTag();      
            if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                button_list.get(7).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                button_list.get(7).setTag("1"); 
            }else{
                    button_list.get(7).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                    button_list.get(7).setTag("0"); 
            }
            break;
        case button8:
            if(button_list.get(8).getTag().equals("0"))
                enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(8).getText().toString());
            is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(8).getTag();      
            if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                button_list.get(8).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                button_list.get(8).setTag("1"); 
            }else{
                    button_list.get(8).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                    button_list.get(8).setTag("0"); 
            }
            break;
        case button9:
            if(button_list.get(9).getTag().equals("0"))
                enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(9).getText().toString());
            is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(9).getTag();      
            if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                button_list.get(9).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                button_list.get(9).setTag("1"); 
            }else{
                    button_list.get(9).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                    button_list.get(9).setTag("0"); 
            }
            break;
            case button10:
                if(button_list.get(10).getTag().equals("0"))
                    enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(10).getText().toString());
                is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(10).getTag();     
                if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                    button_list.get(10).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                    button_list.get(10).setTag("1");    
                }else{
                        button_list.get(10).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                        button_list.get(10).setTag("0");    
                }
                break;
```

Is there a way I can use a general variable to access each `case` so if I make a change I won't need to make it 50 times for each button? I thought about doing something like this:

```
public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case button[i] 
            if(button_list.get(i).getTag().equals("0"))
                enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+button_list.get(i).getText().toString());
            is_clicked= (String)button_list.get(i).getTag();      
            if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
                button_list.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                button_list.get(i).setTag("1"); 
            }else{
                    button_list.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                    button_list.get(i).setTag("0"); 
            }
            break;
```

Would this work? Or is there something else I need to do so I don't need to make 50 changes to my code every time I decide I want to change the `OnClick` method?

Comment: Are the contents of `button_list` the buttons themselves? That is, if `v.getId(()` is `button14` then `button_list.get(14)` is the same view as `v` (passed to `ButtonOnClick`)?

Comment: yes button_list contents are the buttons themselves and yes to the other question (I think?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `ButtonOnClick` is the click handler for the buttons. I'm going to further assume that for any `i`, the contents of `button_list.get(i)` is the button. If that's right, then the argument `v` is the same `Button` object stored in the list. You can then reduce your entire handler to:

```
public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {
    Button btn = (Button) v;
    if (btn.getTag().equals("0")) {
        enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+btn.getText().toString());
    }
    is_clicked= (String) btn.getTag();
    if ("0".equals(is_clicked)){
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
        btn.setTag("1"); 
    }else{
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
        btn.setTag("0"); 
    }
}
```

As an aside, you might consider using `Boolean` objects instead of `String` objects as the button tags.

Comment: You are right with your assumptions. But with your code, how does the program know If I click on the 3rd button or 15th button? All it says is Button btn = (Button) v

Comment: @user2456977 - Looking at the code for the click handler, it doesn't do anything different from one button to another. The program knows which button to modify (the tag and background) because it is passed as an argument.

Comment: Will Works great, just beware if you have another button that does totally something else.

Comment: @VincentD. - Presumably that would have a different click handler. But if it goes into the same method, then, yes, you have a great point.

Comment: It's more the generic name that bother me. That's why I wanted to raise a warning on this.

Answer (score 1):

First you should **never copy paste** code, try to **extract** your code in another method.

If you are using a arraylist where you store all your buttons, you can probably use the `ArrayList.indexOf(Object o)`
So just replace your ButtonOnClick method with this one, you can handle other buttons behavior easily too in the future :

```
public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {
    if(button_list.contains(v))
    {
            setButtonBackground(button_list.indexOf(v));
    }
}

private setButtonBackground(int buttonNumber)
{
    Button myButton = (Button) button_list.get(buttonNumber);

    if(myButton.getTag().equals("0"))
    {
        enter_txt.setText(enter_txt.getText()+myButton.getText().toString());
    }

    is_clicked = (String) myButton.getTag();   

    if ("0".equals(is_clicked))
    {
        myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
        myButton.setTag("1"); 
    }
    else
    {
        myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
        myButton.setTag("0"); 
    }
}
```

When you are developping instead of copy and paste code, just use the shortcut **extract to a method** so you will get something like this and will save yourself time.

```
[...]
case button1:
        setButtonBackground(1);
        break;
case button2:
        setButtonBackground(2);
        break;
[...]
```

Let me know if it works for you